# .htaccess RewriteCond with multiple server variables

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, web

How can i do something like that using htaccess?

```
if (is_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/my_dir'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))
{
    // send file $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/my_dir'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
}
else
{
    // forward to front-end controller
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# load /my_dir/<file> if exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/my_dir/$1 -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /my_dir/$1.php [L]

# otherwise use front controller
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```